# Incompatible version of bundler for Ruby

Tags: ruby, bundler

I am not even new to ruby.  I have to get an existing application running which is used as an interface to a Java application (which I understand).  When I am trying to obtain all the dependencies (on Linux Mint), I am greeted with the following:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/......
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.5)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

I tried 'gem install bundler', but this didn't work.  I tried to install bundler 1.0.0, using:

```
$ sudo gem install bundler -v 1.0.0
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.0.0...
```

This seem to have worked, but I cannot 'switch' to it.

Comment: How does your gemfile look like? have you tried? `bundle update`

Comment: Yes I have - it seems it wants an older version? I find it very weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify what version of a Gem executable to use by specifying the version surrounded by underscores (`_`) after the command, e.g.

```
a_gem_executable _1.2.3_ other args
```

So in order to specifically run version 1.0.0 of bundler, try this:

```
bundle _1.0.0_ install
```

When I tried with 1.0.0, bundler threw an exception, so you might want to try with a more up to date version that’s still compatible with the `~> 1.0.0` specifier:

```
gem install bundler -v 1.0.18
bundle _1.0.18_ install
```

It does strike me as slightly unusual to have bundler itself specified in the Gemfile, you might be able to just remove that line as the simpler alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It pointed me in the correct direction.